# ios App(Swift) Localization

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have facing these problems.

1. I have multiple xibs in my app, how to move strings of all xib's into single file, I have searched on internet, explanation is available with older xcode, is their any new way to do this with ios 9.
2. I am using cocoa pods for various libraries, and those libraries have already done localization, so their localized language is showing in my app, how to separate my localization with theirs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to have all localizations (storyboard, xib .m and .swift files) in one file. Then you need to localize storyboard and xib file throw code. It means you need connect all UI elements from storyboards and xibs to source code (*.m and *.swift). In the way like shown below. In this case you will have one file for localization as example Localizable.strings.

```
@IBOutlet weak var hintLabel: UILabel!
hintLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("localized_text", comment: "Text hint explains what to do in the activate view.")
```

2. To separate your localization from 3rd party localization you need to have separate localization file as example Localizable.strings.

Here is how to do localization throw several files:

1. In the Xcode project editor, select the project or target.
2. Choose Editor > Export For Localization.
3. In the sheet that appears, enter a location in the Save As field.

You can read it more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW1).

Comment: Actually my problem is whenever i am adding any new language, its only showing option to choose my storyBoard only , its not showing my xib files, so how to get strings out of xib files?    Note - I am attaching screen shot.